# JAVA OOP concept issue

Tags: java

Hello guys could you help me please how to render this code as OOP?

I want to improve this code and follow the OOP anyone could help me, please

thank you in advance

this is class Expression

```
class Expression {
        public int type;
        public int value;
        public Expression leftOp;
        public Expression rightOp;
    
        public Expression(int type, int value, Expression leftOp, Expression rightOp) {
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
            this.leftOp = leftOp;
            this.rightOp = rightOp;
        }
    }


    class Arith {
    

/** Constantes pour representer les types */
        public static final int TYPE_NUMBER = 1;
        public static final int TYPE_SUM = 2;
        public static final int TYPE_PROD = 3;

    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
            Expression term = new Expression(TYPE_SUM, 0, new Expression(TYPE_NUMBER, 3, null, null), new Expression(
                    TYPE_PROD, 0, new Expression(TYPE_NUMBER, 2, null, null), new Expression(TYPE_NUMBER, 5, null, null)));
            System.out.println(evaluate(term));
        }
    
        /** Evalue recursivement the expression */
        public static int evaluate(Expression term) {
            switch (term.type) {
            case TYPE_NUMBER:
                return term.value;
            case TYPE_SUM:
                return evaluate(term.leftOp) + evaluate(term.rightOp);
            case TYPE_PROD:
                return evaluate(term.leftOp) * evaluate(term.rightOp);
            default:
                return 0; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Comment: Hi @Reinderien thank you for yiour feedback,

Comment: the code  construct the expression 3 + 2 * 5 and display the result in the terminal the value 13

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

The basic structure isn't bad, but is more structured programming in the C or PASCAL tradition than OOP.

### OOP discussion

You currently have three types of expressions that need different evaluation behaviour, but use only one class `Expression`. You implement this differing behaviour in your main class, using a `switch` on a type code.

Instead, make `Expression` an interface (or a super class if you aren't comfortable yet with interfaces) with an `evaluate()` method, and three classes implementing that interface: `NumberExpression`, `SumExpression`, and `ProductExpression`, each with its own way of doing the `evaluate()` method, with its own fields, and its own constructor (using only the parameters necessary to that type of expression).

Then, there's no need for a type code any more. The Java OOP system does the switch for you. The evaluation of an expression happens where it should happen, in the expression's own class, and you can eliminate the main `evaluate()` method. And it's totally easy to create additional expression types like difference, quotient or power. You just add another class.

The main idea of OOP is that an object's behaviour should be implemented in the corresponding class, especially if the behaviour depends on something you'd call a type.

### Minor points

The type code you are currently using (if it weren't made obsolete by the OOP refactoring) should not be a list of integer constants, but become an `enum`.

Avoid `public` fields, make them `private`, and if really needed, create getter and setter methods. Fields represent some internal state of an object, and nobody outside should manipulate that state, or even have any assumptions on the inner workings of a class. Communication should only happen by calling public methods. (Fields can be viewed as private sticky notes of some clerk, they're not meant to be seen or modified by anybody else, and even asking this clerk about one of these notes seems like bad habit.)

If you have distinct cases how to create instances of a class, create multiple constructors. Your single `Expression` constructor is a "one-size-fits-all" one. When creating a constant number, you still have to supply two irrelevant `Expression`s (given as `null` in your example), and when creating a sum or a product, you are forced to provide an equally irrelevant `value` parameter.